# How to configure NextAuth when provider is at different URL's between client and server?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a situation where the URL that my OIDC provider is sitting at changes whether you are trying from the server side or the client side. I am using Keycloak, and have deployed Keycloak to a Kubernetes cluster. I am also deploying my NextJS app in that same k8s cluster. This creates the following situation:

Users can reach the NextJS app from app.domain.com and get served the home page.

The user presses the login button which calls the signIn('keycloak') function.

Now there are two options.

1. I set the issuer in the Keycloak provider config to be auth.domain.com. This is the domain that the Keycloak instance is exposed from by the K8's cluster. If I do this the following error occurs:

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 {
  error: {
    message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80',
    stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80\n' +
      '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16)\n' +
      '    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)',
    name: 'Error'
  },
  providerId: 'keycloak',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80'
}
```

2. I set the issuer in the Keycloak provider config to be keycloak-svc.namespace.svc.cluster.local. This is the host that Keycloak can be reached at from inside the cluster. When I set this, the error goes away, so it has reached Keycloak's well known endpoint. However, it then tries to redirect the client application to keycloak-svc.namespace.svc.cluster.local and I get an error on the client side because this address cannot be found.

I believe what is happening here is NextAuth is trying to hit the well-known endpoint before redirecting the user. How can I fix this? I've considered trying to play with the /etc/hosts in my NextJS apps container so that it can also reach the Keycloak instance at auth.domain.com but haven't had any luck with that. How can I configure the provider/next-auth so that it finds the well-known endpoint at a different base URL than that it redirects to?

Thanks.